# subtract max of column from all entries in column R

Tags: r, max, subtraction

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
kfm <- data.frame ("data_source"=c("kfm", "kfm", "kfm", "kfm"), 
               "1996"= c(56, 56, 56, 57), 
               "1997"=c(8, 8, 9, 7),
               "1998"= c(101, 102, 101, 105))
```

I want to subtract the max of each column from each of the year columns (in my data frame I have about 20 years). So if the max of 1996 is 57. So I want to subtract 57 from each of the 1996 entries. And the max for 1997 is 9, so I would want to subtract 9 from each of the 1997 entries. I want the resulting data frame to look like:

```
kfm_differences <- data.frame ("data_source"=c("kfm", "kfm", "kfm", "kfm"), 
               "1996"= c(-1, -1, -1, 0), 
               "1997"=c(-1, -1, 0, -2),
               "1998"= c(-4, -3, -4, 0))
```

So that each entry now shows the difference between the max and the entry. I'm not sure how to go about this. I feel like I need to use `apply()` somehow, but I'm not quite sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple.

```
kfm_differences <- kfm
kfm_differences[-1] <- lapply(kfm[-1], function(x) x - max(x))
```

By the way, when creating data frames with column names that start with numerals, use argument `check.names = FALSE`, otherwise R will append a `X`.

Comment: oh okay thanks! I didn't know about the check.names thing. This worked great!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
kfm_differences = data.frame(data_source = kfm$data_source, mapply("-", kfm[-1], lapply(kfm[-1], max)))
```

> ```
> #> kfm_differences
> #  data_source X1996 X1997 X1998
> #1         kfm    -1    -1    -4
> #2         kfm    -1    -1    -3
> #3         kfm    -1     0    -4
> #4         kfm     0    -2     0
> ```

## Explanation

- We get the maximum value per column with `lapply(kfm[-1], max)`
- Then we subtract each of these values from each column of `kfm` using `mapply("-", kfm[-1], lapply(kfm[-1], max))`
- Finally, we build our resulting `data.frame` with the correct naming for the `data_source` column using `data.frame(data_source = kfm$data_source, mapply("-", kfm[-1], lapply(kfm[-1], max)))`

Answer (score 0):

This may be accomplished using a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) approach as well with the `mutate_if` verb from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
dplyr::mutate_if(kfm, is.numeric, funs(. - max(.)))

#   data_source X1996 X1997 X1998
# 1         kfm    -1    -1    -4
# 2         kfm    -1    -1    -3
# 3         kfm    -1     0    -4
# 4         kfm     0    -2     0
```